# How to compile a C program using a library

Tags: c, libraries

I'm fairly new to programming in C. For my thesis I have to use the library "Libquantum" from the site http://www.libquantum.de/. I write my code in notepad and compile using the command window. I downloaded mingw and compile with gcc.

For normal C programs everything works fine. I use, for example,  the command `gcc -o HelloWorld HelloWorld.c` and the program compiles fine. But I can't manage to compile programs where I use the library...

I downloaded the library and used the commands `./configure`, `make`, ..., `make install` like they mentioned in the installation guide (https://github.com/jonbaer/libquantum/blob/master/INSTALL). After the last command the command window showed this:

[image]

I made sure to include `#include <quantum.h>` in the code and tried the linker flag `-lquantum` on different places when I try to compile but nothing works...

When I try to compile i get the following error

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lquantum
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: What is the problem? The output in the image shows that installing the library succeeded. Please show the code where you try to use the library and how you tried to compile it.

Comment: Please include the exact errors you're getting.  Also, copy/pasting output is usually a better option than including screenshots.

Comment: I highly recommend using a real IDE, ideally on the same system. Have you considered a Linux VM?

Comment: Please don't show pure text as graphics. It's much more readable if you add text commands and messages as text into your question.

Comment: @Nick : MInGW is a native Windows GNU toolchain, not a Linux environment (like Cygwin for example).  The MSYS shell is a minimal shell primarily to support library porting using configure/make/install; it is not a given (or even likely) that the intent is to target Linux.  But the suggestion to use an IDE is good.  Suggest Code::Blocks - the Windows version includes MInGW.  MSYS remains useful however for building third-party library code ported from Linux.

Comment: Now why would you not include the exact command line you were using as well as the errors?  Also post plain text as text using code mark-up - not a _picture of text_.

Answer (score 0):

As the `make install` output says you need to tell the linker where the library is using a `-L<path>` option.  The `make install` places the library in `\usr\local\lib`.  If you are performing the build in MSYS, you can probably use `-L\usr\local\lib`, but if you have moved the file, change as necessary.

If you are building from cmd.exe (Windows's shell) rather than MSYS, you'll have to use its native a Windows path.

Comment: I tried to add `-L\usr\local\lib` on multiple places but still get an error everytime. for example when i try 
`gcc -o shor -L\usr\local\lib shor.c -lquantum`
i get the same error as mentioned above.